# Красивое оформление страницы. генератор HTML

Tags: html, css, шаблоны

Всем привет. Все сталкивались с конструктарами, где предлагают готовое оформление страницы, где нужно просто редактировать текст и страничка с красивым оформлением готова. А есть ли сервис, где нужно делать тоже самое, только в результате получать html и css?

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что такой есть, так как если на сайте присутсвуют, скажем, картинки, то они где-то должны храниться, а в html/css к ним должен быть указан путь. Конструкторы не смогут тебе дать html/css с путями к твоим файлам. Точнее, я думаю, что этого никто не реализовывал.

Comment: Попробуйте [это](http://macaw.co/), насколько я помню раньше можно было получать html/css

Comment: Любой сайт можно скопировать, в том числе тот который сделан на конструкторе, вот только в каком виде ты там получишь html/css - это боль